# Python debugging: step INTO built-in functions and/or standard library classes

Tags: python, list-comprehension, slice

I would like to be able to step INTO the Python built-ins and/or standard library classes and trace execution of my code through all paths.

I think Python might be implemented in C (?) behind the curtains so there may not be anything like what you can do in Java, where you can add sources to Eclipse and see exactly what happens when, for instance, you do an `Arrays.copyOf(...)`. Admittedly, you can't see what happens when you do an `int[] a; a[0] = 42;` in Java either, there is no visible code to walk into for that so the boundary is set somewhere there too.

My thinking was that there might be a Python implementation "in Python" (?) which I could use to see what functions like sorted() and .sort() do and how they work, for educational purposes.

Please consider that I am a total beginner and I may be "immigrating" concepts from Java or other environments with an incompatible philosophy behind them. This is just due to the novelty of the "Python way of thinking" for me.

I have noticed that I can trace through some packages of which I find the `.py` sources in the installation directory, that's very helpful but it only goes until a certain point.

Note: I realise that even in Java, the limit is reached when I encounter a JNI invocation for example, making anything beyond that totally opaque, and in other cases as well. I am not thinking of instrumenting the JVM and/or attaching a GDB instance to the Python "runtime" with symbols (is there such a thing?) but it would be nice to step INTO the inner workings of the language and its base classes.

Apologies if this post was a little more wordy than others, I thought I might have not explained myself very well at all in my first draft so I thought I would err on the side of "clarity" rather than space. Thanks for you patience and for your explanations.

Note (2): I have no experience with Python *profiling*, I would not even know where to begin with that.

Comment: It seems that you have even tried to use pdb: http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Comment: If you want to know how the builtin functions function (for educational purposes), you can always read the source. :-).  Much of the standard library is implemented in python which makes it a (relatively) easy read for a Saturday night.  Also, note that python is a *language specification*.  Cpython is the most common *implementation*.  It is written in C and is commonly referred to as "python".  There are other implementations though: `jython`  -- python implemented in java and `pypy` -- python implemented in python for example

Comment: Also, if you're particularly interested in sorting, the algorithm that python uses is called the `Timsort` ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort )

Comment: Reading the source gives me the info I need but it's the not the debugger-integrated convenience I was asking about?

Comment: @Robottinosino -- No it doesn't.  I doubt that you'll find that.  python has `pdb` which will allow you to step through python code, but I doubt you can actually step (very far) into builtin functions -- but I can't say for sure.  I've never used it.